# Stack Overflow is very slow after today's short outage

Tags: support, performance

A couple of hours ago there was a very short "Stack Overflow is currently offline" period.

After that the site feels very slow on general browsing, especially on Ajax events. Examples:

[image]
[image]

Uploading the above two pictures involved about a minute worth of waiting for Ajax calls to complete.

Comment: By teh Nick: [We're working on mitigating Stack Overflow site responsiveness issues now, stand by.](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/839057673224130561)

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: Nah, Let it be. Others will ask the same question again, anyway. Nick will add an answer once he's free.

Comment: He's since said it's due to an issue with Caching.

Comment: I was also getting that slow responses, but now i think it's ok

Comment: The caching was a mitigation problem (hash conflicts) - we're still working on the core issue.

Comment: I have noticed this as well. From my observation there seems to be an excessive amount of server side work being done during the request. Perhaps it is related to using https with URL Rewrite?

Comment: To note though, I only seem to notice this on meta. The main site seems to load as expected. In the past I have looked at load times and come to expect roughly 575ms from a page load at Stack Overflow. On meta this seems to have jumped to roughly 990ms on average for normal pages. I can see that client load times are being tracked, which is good, but overall I think (could be wrong) that this feels isolated to meta.

Comment: I am no longer able to reproduce the speed issue.

Comment: Wait, when did we start closing fixed issues as no longer repro'able? If that is the case all the [status-completed] posts must be closed as such.

Comment: @BhargavRao Many years ago.