# Ignoring my favourite tag

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I've just noticed the main page had a lot less orange questions than usual, and indeed fewer interesting ones. Now I realised that my favourite tag, [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), has gone missing from my favourited tags. When I went to [my preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1048572), I saw it right in my "ignored tags"!

How could that have happened? A database hiccup? A clientside settings mess up? I could swear I did not touch my settings in ages, and it's quite unlikely someone played a prank on me. Or are there any one-click buttons I could have clicked by accident without noticing that move a tag from "favourite" to "ignored"?

Comment: You could have accidentally hit the star in the tag info dropdown (while hovering a tag), which would move the tag from your favorites directly to the ignored tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking on the star inside the dialog that pops up when you hover over a tag will toggle the tag between favorite, ignored, and normal.

My guess (and [@Floern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/559745/floern)'s [guess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345166/ignoring-my-favourite-tag#comment455023_345166_)) is that you mis-clicked that star, which would move the tag from your favorite list to your ignored list.

[image]

Comment: That's it. I remember a tag popup loading slowly (due to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345076/1048572)?) and me accidentally hitting something in it instead of the link behind it, but I didn't notice that it caused an action.